# Python 3.7.7 Kivy: Unable to find any valuable Window provider. sdl2 - ValueError: Not a boolean: 400

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm stuck at this problem. I have tried to install all prerequisites that i found in internet. I'm using Windows 10 and CMDer. This error also occured in any of programs of Kivy that i run. Here's the error details.

```
    (kivy_venv) λ python main.py -d
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\DC\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-04-05_71.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.18
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.10
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.23
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "D:\Fazar\Terminal\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "D:\Fazar\Terminal\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.lang> with limit=None, timeout=None
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.image> with limit=None, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.atlas> with limit=None, timeout=None
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.1
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.texture> with limit=1000, timeout=60
[DEBUG  ] [Cache       ] register <kv.shader> with limit=1000, timeout=3600
[DEBUG  ] [App         ] Loading kv <.\pong.kv>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ValueError: Not a boolean: 400
  File "D:\Fazar\Terminal\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "D:\Fazar\Terminal\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "D:\Fazar\Terminal\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 981, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "D:\Fazar\Terminal\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 284, in create_window
    resizable = Config.getboolean('graphics', 'resizable')
  File "D:\Fazar\Software\Python37\lib\configparser.py", line 828, in getboolean
    raw=raw, vars=vars, fallback=fallback, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Fazar\Software\Python37\lib\configparser.py", line 808, in _get_conv
    **kwargs)
  File "D:\Fazar\Software\Python37\lib\configparser.py", line 802, in _get
    return conv(self.get(section, option, **kwargs))
  File "D:\Fazar\Software\Python37\lib\configparser.py", line 1160, in _convert_to_boolean
    raise ValueError('Not a boolean: %s' % value)

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I've installed pygments, pypiwin32, kivy_deps.sdl2, kivy_deps.angle, kivy_deps.gstreamer, and Kivy itself. I have no clue now. Please answer if you have suggestions to fix this.

> Note: Kivy programs ran successfully before and now it didn't work anymore, i've tried reinstall Python 3.7.7 and Kivy few times both in and out virtual environment

Comment: Have you touched the kivy config file? I haven't seen this error before, and it looks like a bad config read.

Comment: @inclement ok, here's the config.ini: https://pastebin.com/jfQ1p0hR

Comment: You have `resizable = 400`. Maybe that's supposed to be 1

Comment: Hmm, nice. But now it shows new error: https://pastebin.com/HNvYdppZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error fixed by configuring `C:\Users\<UserName>\.kivy\config.ini`:

```
[graphics]
display = -1
fullscreen = 0
height = 600
left = 0
maxfps = 60
multisamples = 2
position = auto
rotation = 0
show_cursor = 1
top = 0
width = 800
resizable = 1
borderless = 0
window_state = visible
minimum_width = 0
minimum_height = 0
min_state_time = .035
allow_screensaver = 1
shaped = 0
```

resizable value must be 1 or 0. Or else it could make a windows provider error. And also, install preresquisites to avoid another errors:

1. `python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew kivy.deps.angle`
2. `python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer`